# Creating lft and rgt columns dynamically in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, hierarchical-data, nested-set-model

Can anyone guide me on how to create the lft and rgt columns (parsed from left to right in a tree from root)dynamically for a table using MySQL Query?

The structure of my table looks like this:

```
id----name----parent_id
```

and I want the structure like this :

```
name----lft----rgt
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? There are a lot of tutorials out there which might help you to get started

Comment: Are you using MySQL 8.0? If you are, or if you can upgrade to MySQL 8.0, then you don't need to use the nested set solution for hierarchical data. MySQL 8.0 supports recursive queries, so you don't need the workarounds anymore.

Comment: @Sagnik: sample data and expected results would help clarifying your expectations here.

Answer (score 0):

You can self-join the table and aggregate:

```
select
    t.id
    t.name,
    min(t1.id) left_id,
    max(t1.id) right_id
from mytable t
left join mytable t1 on t1.parent_id = t.id
group by t.id, t.name
```

This assumes exactly two children per node. If some nodes may have one child only, you can add a little logic:

```
select
    t.id
    t.name,
    min(t1.id) left_id,
    case when min(t1.id) <> max(t1.id) then max(t1.id) end right_id
from mytable t
left join mytable t1 on t1.parent_id = t.id
group by t.id, t.name
```

Comment: The left and right numbers in the nested-set model are not id's. They're just ordinals, numbered according to a depth-first traversal of the hierarchy.

Comment: See slides 23-39 of https://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/models-for-hierarchical-data

Comment: @BillKarwin: thank you for the reading and explanation. Well then to transpose the model we would need to traverse the entire tree (this requires MySQL 8.0 though).

Comment: Yes, or a lot of code to read the data into a tree data structure in one's application, then traverse that tree and insert the nodes one at a time into a nested-set data model. It's a PITA.

Answer (score 0):

I don't like the nested-set model for representing hierarchical data in a relational database. It was made popular by Joe Celko's 2004 book "Trees and Hierarchies in SQL for Smarties" and by a [blog post by Mike Hillyer](http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/) which dates back at least to 2010.

One problem with the nested-set model is that adding nodes to the hierarchy must be done one node at a time, because every node inserted to the tree requires renumbering the `left` and `right` from the point of insertion to the right side of the tree.

A friend suggested to me to use floating-point numbers instead of integers for `left` and `right`, then you can just use fractional values in between the existing numbers when you insert a new node to the tree.

Another problem with the nested-set model is that the `left` and `right` values aren't references to any other data elements. In fact, the make no sense except in their relationship to the `left` and `right` values of other nodes. So there's no data integrity, and it's easy for data anomalies to corrupt your hierarchy.

The only hierarchical model with data integrity is the one you've already got — storing `parent_id` in each node's row. There's no way for data anomalies to exist when every node knows its own parent, and there will be no argument or conflict with any other rows.

The downside of that model, called the Adjecency List model, is that MySQL doesn't support recursive queries until version 8.0. See examples in https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html